# How to implement `Wait` or `Event handler` function into CATVBA?

Tags: vba, catia

I have into a `UserForm` some `Label`. This `Label` after an event `Click()` runs a function that should wait for `Selection` event but I have no idea how to realize it with `CATVBA`.

```
Private Sub lblSomeLabel_Click()

    Dim oSelection As Selection
    Set oSelection = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection
    
    Dim oPartDocument As PartDocument
    Set oPartDocument = CATIA.ActiveDocument
    
    UserForm.Hide
    
    ' ------------
    ' HERE I NEED SOME HELP ;)
    ' I NEED TO `SWITCH` TO CATIA AND MAKE A SELECTION
    ' AND THEN RETURN TO EXECUTE THE REST OF THE CODE
    ' ------------
    
    If oSelection.Count > 0 Then
        ' DO SOME STUFF
    End If

    UserForm.Show
      
End Sub
```

I really appreciate your support!

Comment: In CATScript no userforms are possible, so I guess you ask about VBA (or CATvba). Please check the method `SelectElement2` in the documentation. Use the return value of the selectelement to check if the user has canceled the selection.

Comment: You're right @Shrotter, I mean `CATVBA`. I corrected the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Shrotter suggested I used the `selectElement2` method. It can't be used directly in `CATVBA`, so I used it in a separate function and called it.

```
Private Sub lblSomeLabel_Click()

    Dim oSelection As Selection
    Set oSelection = CATIA.ActiveDocument.Selection
    
    Dim oPartDocument As PartDocument
    Set oPartDocument = CATIA.ActiveDocument
    
    UserForm.Hide
    
    ' ------------
    Call MyModule.SelectElement() 
    ' ------------
    
    If oSelection.Count > 0 Then
        ' DO SOME STUFF
    End If

    UserForm.Show

    Set oPartDocument = Nothing
    Set oSelection = Nothing
      
End Sub
```

```
'MyModule.SelectElement()
Function SelectElement()

    Set oActiveDocument = CATIA.ActiveDocument
    Set oSelection = oActiveDocument.Selection

    Dim InputObjectType(1)

    'Set the selection type
    InputObjectType(0) = "Plane"
    InputObjectType(1) = "Face"

    'Get the status
    oStatus = oSelection.SelectElement2(InputObjectType, "Select Face or Plane element", True)

    Set oActiveDocument = Nothing
    Set oSelection = Nothing

End Function
```

Thank you!